# failed to import utf16 encoded file into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, import

I have txt pipe-delimited file (non-english - given below is Polish, but other langs are also involved), encoded utf16, something like:

```
head1|head2|head3|head4
brytyjski wytwórca|z jakże bogatą|przedwojenną historią|zapowiedział wypuszczenie
dziś znamy|jedynie paletę kolorów|obejmującą aż|jedną pozycję
```

I tried lots of different ways to get it into mysql table:

- line-by-line using php
- using LOAD DATA INFILE via console in any way I could conceive, e.g.:

```
 
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/\wamp/\www/\hmvc/\prop_tst.txt' INTO TABLE hmvc.table CHARACTER SET 'utf8' FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' \g
```

I always get either:

- garbled (wrongly encoded) entries
- nothing gets entered (sql writes default values)

Just to mention: I also set table in utf8, utf16, latin2 (for Eastern European encoding) ... and nada.

BTW:
When I change encoding , e.g. in Notepad to utf8 I can import - no problem, but what if I have chars requiring utf16 (Asian), or I want to automate file input?

Php iconv etc. seems not to be up to the job.

Any help, link to some reading etc. would be much appreciated, as I am freshly out of ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As documented under [`LOAD DATA INFILE` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data.html):

> #### Note
>
> It is not possible to load data files that use the `ucs2`, `utf16`, or `utf32` character set.

UTF-8 can represent the same full set of Unicode codepoints as UTF-16.  Perhaps it'd be easiest to use only that encoding (or transcode the file prior to import in some other language, such as via PHP's `iconv()` function)?

Comment: you are right about that NOTE - so conversion to UTF8 before upload - this poses a question: would that not garble Asian chars?

Comment: @Jeffz: No, as I said, "*UTF-8 can represent the same full set of Unicode codepoints as UTF-16.*"

Answer (score 2):

You **can not** import **UTF-16** formatted **.txt** files (or as Microsoft calls them "**UNICODE**" text files) into MySQL. You can read about that statement [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-reslimits-excerpt/5.6/en/charset-restrictions.html).  What I found the best option to do was - download [TextPad](https://www.textpad.com/download/) and open your text file, then click **Save As** and make sure you select for **ENCODING:** **UTF-8**. Then you can load that file directly into your SQL Table easily. I uploaded about 2.5 million records in less than 10 seconds.

> **It is currently not possible to use LOAD DATA INFILE to load data files that use these character sets.** - [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-reslimits-excerpt/5.6/en/charset-restrictions.html)

Comment: The link in "You can read about that statement here" is not a URL. Please add the missing link.

Comment: @Andrei That's because they have removed the website I was referencing, that doesn't merit a down vote. Anyways, it's fixed now.

Comment: Sorry, I guess i got swept away during the rush of the search, thanks for answering.

Comment: No problem, it happens.

Comment: If using Notepad++ instead of TextPad, you can use the menu Encoding / Convert to UTF-8 then save the file.